# Bar chart - bar title rotation

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm using `achartengine` lib and I have problem with displaying of bars value. I want to display multiply bar chart, but when the values are similar, the text is not good for readability.

Does any one provide some ideas for improving this? Or exists another library for bar chart, where it is possible to do this?

[image: See picture here.]

Answer (score 1):

Use this library [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

It supports multiple type of charts and also dragging, zooming etc.